# Transform sales order to Return Authorization with specific items - SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I need to transform a sales order to return authorization with specific line items, not will all line items available on the sales order.

Let's say I have a sales order created with 3 items

1. Item one with qty 2
2. Item two with qty 1
3. Item three with qty 4

this order fulfilled completely and billed.

Now, **the customer wanted to return Item two with qty 1  and Item three with qty 2**, I want to transform (using suite script 2.0) my sales order to return authorization with only return items, I don't want to include items that are not returned.

Returned items are available in array;

```
const returned_items = [{ item: 'item two', qty: 1 }, { item: 'item three', qty: 2 }];
var returnAuthorizationRecord = record.transform({
    fromType: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
    fromId: orderId,
    toType: record.Type.RETURN_AUTHORIZATION,
    isDynamic: true,
    defaultValues: {
        customform: CUSTOM_FORMS_RMA.CREDIT
    }
});
const lineCount = returnAuthorizationRecord.getLineCount({
    sublistId: 'item'
});
for (var i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {
    returnAuthorizationRecord.selectLine({ sublistId: 'item', line: i });    
    // Do I need to first remove all line items and then add retuned items available in array
    returnAuthorizationRecord.removeLine({
        sublistId: 'item',
        line: 3,
        ignoreRecalc: true
    });
    // Or loop through each line and match with item, if item matches then update accordingly if not then remove from the list?
}

returnAuthorizationRecord.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  You should remove items from the transformed object.  Explanation of why:  the transform method will fill in some, shall we say, obscure, fields that will associate the return line items and (thus) the RMA with the original sales order.  Keeping that association typically ends up being important for your users and data consistency.

Code:

```
const returned_items = [{ item: 'item two', qty: 1 }, { item: 'item three', qty: 2 }];
...
const returned_item_map = returned_items.reduce(function (result, x) {
    result[x.item] = true;
    return result
}, {});
var lines_to_remove = []
for (var i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {
    returnAuthorizationRecord.selectLine({ sublistId: 'item', line: i });    
    var item_name = returnAuthorizationRecord.getCurrentSublistText({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'item'
    });
    if (item_name in returned_item_map) {
        // do whatever processing you want to do here
    }
    else {
        lines_to_remove.push(i);     
    }
}
// make sure to remove lines in reverse order
lines_to_remove.reverse();
lines_to_remove.forEach(function (i) {
    returnAuthorizationRecord.removeLine({
        sublistId: 'item',
        line: i
    });
});
```